# Track which button was clicked; clear data if the current button clicked was different than the previous button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic web page that populates with gifs of my choice.Below is a screenshot of the page.

[image: Screenshot of webpage]

**Summary** : 
Clicking on the buttons above grabs the giphy images and displays on the screen. Let's say I click on Chris Pratt, it should display all the images on the screen for Chris Pratt. Clicking on Chris Pratt each subsequent time should grab 10 more images and append to the screen. New clicking on Tom Cruise should empty $('#actors-view') and displays giphys for Tom Cruise. Again clicking on Tom Cruise should append 10 images to the exisiting Tom cruise giphy.

**Issue**:The issue I am having is what needs to be done to empty $('#actors-view') when a new button is clicked. Currently, when the $('#actors-view') is empty,I call `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${actor}&api_key=[API_KEY]`. This grabs the initial number of giphys; each additional clicks to the same button grabs additional giphys on the screen. The issue is when I click on a different button, **it appends all the current giphys to the new giphys.** Example, I will have all the pictures of Dwayne Johnson mixed with Chris Hemsworthh; which is not what I want.

[image]

```
#Index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-5" id="buttons-view"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="actors-view"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button
              class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              type="button"
              id="add-actor"
            >
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
          <input
            id="actor-input"
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add an actor"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


#app.js

    let topics = [
  'Tom Cruise',
  'Arnold Schwarzenegger',
  'Tom Hanks',
  'Chris Hemsworth',
  'Chris Pratt',
  'Dwayne Johnson',
  'Will Smith',
  'Vin Diesel',
  'Pamela Anderson',
  'Shahrukh khan',
  'Hrithik Roshan'
];

//initial call of the function to render the buttons on screen
renderButtons();

function renderButtons() {
  $('#buttons-view').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    var a = $('<button>');
    a.addClass('actor btn btn-info');
    a.attr('data-name', topics[i]);
    a.text(topics[i]);
    $('#buttons-view').append(a);
  }
}

function ajaxCall(queryURL) {
  $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);

    var actors = response.data;
    //for each of the JSON data
    actors.forEach(actor => {
      //grab the images.fixed_height.url
      imgURL = actor.images.downsized.url;
      //grab the rating
      rating = actor.rating;

      // Creating an element to have the rating displayed
      pOne = $('<p>').text('Rating: ' + rating);
      //create a new div
      giphyDiv = $("<div class='giphy'>");
      //append the p element to the giphyDiv
      giphyDiv.append(pOne);
      //create an image tag and define the src
      image = $('<img>').attr('src', imgURL);
      //append the image to the div
      giphyDiv.prepend(image);

      //append the div to the image in the div
      $('#actors-view').prepend(giphyDiv);
    });
  });
}

// Function for dumping the JSON content for each button into the div
function displayActorInfo() {
  var actor = $(this).attr('data-name');
  if ($('#actors-view').is(':empty')) {
    var queryURL = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${actor}&api_key=API_KEY`;

    ajaxCall(queryURL);
  } else {
    var queryURL = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${actor}&api_key=API_KEY&limit=10`;

    ajaxCall(queryURL);
  }
}

// This function handles events where one button is clicked
$('#add-actor').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // This line grabs the input from the textbox
  var actor = $('#actor-input')
    .val()
    .trim();
  //If there are text in thhe textbox then push it to the topics array
  if (actor) {
    topics.push(actor);
    console.log(topics);
  }
  //empty the value in the text-box
  $('#actor-input').val(' ');

  //call the function to re-render the buttons in the screen after the update
  renderButtons();
});

// Function for displaying the actors info
// Using $(document).on instead of $(".actor").on to add event listeners to dynamically generated elements
$(document).on('click', '.actor', displayActorInfo);
```

Comment: Seems like you need to track which button was clicked and then clear the output area if the current button clicked was different than the previous button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function() {
    if (
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .data('lastClicked')
    ) {
      lastActorButtonCLicked= $(this)
        .parent()
        .data('lastClicked');
    }
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .data('lastClicked', this.id);
  });
});

// Function for dumping the JSON content for each button into the div
function displayActorInfo() {
  var actor = $(this).attr('data-name');

  console.log(actor);
  console.log(lastActorButtonCLicked)

  if ($('#actors-view').is(':empty') || actor !== lastActorButtonCLicked) {
    var queryURL = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${actor}&api_key=BkaUZZWcFij6J7AoQj3WtPb1R2p9O6V9`;

    imd = true;

    ajaxCall(queryURL, imd);
  } else {
    var queryURL = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${actor}&api_key=BkaUZZWcFij6J7AoQj3WtPb1R2p9O6V9&limit=10`;
    imd = false;
    ajaxCall(queryURL, imd);
  }
}
```